# how string (command line) are stored in char**argv and int *argv?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

*First snippet:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int i;
for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
return 0;
}
```

load time input :

> ./a.out devang samir

output:

> devang
>      samir

*Second snippet:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, int *argv)
{
int i;
for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
return 0;
}
```

load time input :

> ./a.out devang samir

output:

> devang
>      samir

in both case, i got output same, but why?

- in first case how the strings (command line ) are stored in char** argv ?
- in second case how the string (command line ) are stored in int * argv...?

Comment: The second program exhibits [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior). Anything can happen (even working like a correct program).

Comment: There is a reason this is called **undefined** behaviour. Any reason you do not just use the correct version, but shoot your foot?

Comment: what that reason ? @Olaf

Comment: While my question was more rhetorical, I do not understand what your problem is with it.

Comment: It sounds like this post was more out of curiosity than to solve a genuine problem, since OP knows the correct declaration.  The reason it works for you is that on your system, an `int` apparently has the same size as a `char *` (a pointer), so the first-level access still "works".  Then you're passing the pointer to `printf`, as an `int` rather than `char *`, but aside from a bunch of compiler warnings, the actual code is probably the same, and `printf` is able to treat the `int` as a `char *` to print the string.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Once you invoke undefined behaviour there is no use asking "why does it work". Even more, OP should get compiler warnings. If not, he should use a modern compiler, like gcc. No need to mention warnings shall be enabled.

Comment: @Olaf OP certainly should have gotten warnings.  I agree that it's not a particularly good use of time to try to figure out why undefined behavior sometimes does what was intended, but that does seem to be the sole purpose of OP's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `C11` standard specifies the function signature for `main()` in chapter §5.1.2.2.1 as

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;[...]

and regarding the constrains,

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings,[...]

Then, in your second case,

```
 int main(int argc, int *argv)
```

`char*`  and `int` ( for `argv[n]`, in general) are being different types altogether (i.e, not compatible type), your second program invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, in case of the functions without having a prototype, the parameters passed to the function while calling should *exactly* match the type of expected arguments.

Quoting the standard, chapter §6.5.2.2

> [...] If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of
>   the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after
>   promotion, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: You mean `char *` and `int`, not `char` and `int`.

Comment: @TomKarzes sorry I did not get you. Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: OP used `int` in place of `char *`, not `char`.  Correct type:  `char **`  Incorrect type:  `int *`.  The difference is that a `char *` in the correct type was replaced by `int` in the incorrect type.  That's why it "works":  `int` and `char *` apparently have the same size on OP's machine.  `int` and `char` do not.

Comment: @TomKarzes this looks better?